# How to add <Link> in array data react-bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

[image]

Why i get [object object] after add a  react-bootstrap-table

```
 datas: [
          { id: 1, kode: 11,provinsi: <Link to="lap/DetailYankb/provinsi?provinsi=ACEH">ACEH</Link>,jmlhTempatPelKb:2323,jmlhFKTRL:310,klinikUtama:291,rsUmum:300,rsKhusus:400,jumlahFKTP:289,puskesmas:192,praktekDokter:255,klinikPratama:90,rsTipeD:400,jumlahJaringan:120,pustu:301,pusling:532,praktikBidan:90,poskendes:34},
        ],
```

Solved by [How to add href to react-bootstrap-table column dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894031/how-to-add-href-to-react-bootstrap-table-column-dynamically)

Comment: It is treating your link as a string. Can you show the code for how your table is displayed, not only the source data? And please use text, not a screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894031/how-to-add-href-to-react-bootstrap-table-column-dynamically

Solved from that thx

Comment: yup, that question solve my problem